# Connection between spaces of cosets and homotopy cofibers

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homotopy-theory

Suppose we have an inclusion of a closed sub-Lie group $H\to G$ and take the space of left cosets of $H$, $G/H$.  How is this related to the homotopy cofiber of the inclusion of topological spaces $cof(\iota:H\to G)$, i.e. "coning off" $H$ in $G$.  Are they homotopy equivalent?

Comment: You could try look in Mimura-Toda and see if they talk about anything like this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the following is a counterexample.
Consider $H:= \{\pm 1\}\subset G:= U(1)$. Then $G/H = RP^1$, whereas the cone on the inclusion is homotopy equivalent to $S^1\vee S^1$.